# Can't upload CSV to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, csv, file-upload

I have been using PostgreSQL for a while now, and I have connected my IDE PyCharm with my local PostgreSQL. I just dumped the data of one of my database with 295 rows to a csv, and tried to import the same file, and it shows me an error. I checked the csv and the columns multiple times, but it keeps giving me the same error, without importing a single line.

### The error I keep getting

> 1:1: ERROR: null value in column "Name" violates not-null constraint   Detail: Failing row contains (1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Tempo 407  1500).

This is a screenshot of my database:
[image: db]

This is my model:

```
class Truckdb(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    TruckID = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    Length = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Breadth = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Height = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Volume = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Weight = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    Price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

This is how my csv looks like:

```
1,Tempo 407,OPEN,1,9.5,5.5,5.5,287.375,1500,1,Tempo 407  1500
2,Tempo 407,OPEN,2,9.5,5.5,5.5,287.375,2000,1,Tempo 407  2000
3,Tempo 407,OPEN,3,9.5,5.5,5.5,287.375,2500,2,Tempo 407  2500
4,13 Feet,OPEN,4,13,5.5,7,500.5,3500,3,13 Feet  3500
5,14 Feet,OPEN,5,14,6,6,504,4000,3,14 Feet  4000
6,17 Feet,OPEN,6,17,6,7,672,6000,4,17 Feet  6000
7,18 Feet Taurus,OPEN,7,18,7,7,882,8000,6,18 Feet Taurus  8000
8,19 Feet Taurus,OPEN,8,19,7,7,931,9000,10,19 Feet Taurus  9000
9,10 TYRE,OPEN,9,22,7.5,8,1320,14000,11,10 TYRE  14000
10,10 TYRE,OPEN,10,22,7.5,8,1320,15000,12,10 TYRE  15000
11,10 TYRE,OPEN,11,22,7.5,8,1320,16000,12,10 TYRE  16000
12,12 TYRE,OPEN,12,22,7.5,8,1320,20000,15,12 TYRE  20000
13,12 TYRE,OPEN,13,22,7.5,8,1320,21000,16,12 TYRE  21000
14,12 TYRE,OPEN,14,22,7.5,8,1320,22000,16,12 TYRE  22000
15,14 TYRE,OPEN,15,22,7.5,8,1320,24000,16,14 TYRE  24000
16,14 TYRE,OPEN,16,22,7.5,8,1320,25000,16,14 TYRE  25000
17,14 TYRE,OPEN,17,22,7.5,8,1320,26000,16,14 TYRE  26000
```

Why is the first row content of csv >'Tempo 407' creating an error of null? And why are rest of all the rows getting Null here??

[image: screen]
This is the screen I get just before uploading the data. Here, as you can see, everything is in correct format. But, when I do upload, it tells me Name cannot have null, and failing row contains all null except the first id column and the last column *display name*. My name column is charfield so, I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Is it considering the first row of the csv to be the header?  Perhaps try adding a header row and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: I tried with/without headers. I even marked first row as headers.

Comment: So how do you import this data? Apparently it gets corrupted before reaching postgresql.

Comment: @DanielVérité I upload using the option : 'Import data from File'. I then choose my csv file, and it displays the screen show in the edit.